# How to find dropped source in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have many ListView which contains items, some have content and some do not. I want to show filled box on the position of empty box. How to find out Id of filled box when we drag and how to find Dropbox position and detail of empty box and Listview? Listview Item showing as tile. And also describe types of event.

See Image

[image]

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FieldSchedule}">
                <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource EquipmentItemBackground}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Width="243" Height="35"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" Background="#CFE2FC">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>-->
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Ticket #" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"  
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding OrderID}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="0,0,5,5" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Width="243" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" Height="110" Background="White"  AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Border_DragEnter_1" DragLeave="Border_DragLeave_1" Drop="Border_Drop">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Grid Background="White">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ContactName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,1,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontWeight="Medium"/>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding JobName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,1,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium"/>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding City}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,1,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium"/>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding EarlyIn}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,1,0,0" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding StreetAddress}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,1,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="toggleButton1"  Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="24" Height="30" Padding="0" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0">
                                        <Image  Name="imgCalendar12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Height="30" Source="/Assets/cal.JPG"  Margin="0"/>
                                        <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <ie:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=telerik:RadTileList},Path=DataContext.UnassingedCalendarPopUpComand}"   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton1}">
                                                </ie:InvokeCommandAction>
                                            </ie:EventTrigger>
                                        </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </Button>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <!--<DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadTileList}}}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource EquipmentItemSelectedBackground}" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                </DataTemplate.Triggers>-->
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What does your code look like now (XAML DataTemplate + Class Code)?

Comment: I have updated the question and Here is stop 3 ,4 and  5 is different list not a single list.